# Guineense luso ou apenas luso-guineense?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, palavra-para-ideia, significado-em-contexto

Uma pessoa da Guiné, que também possui nacionalidade portuguesa, pode ser chamada de *guineense luso* ou apenas *luso-guineense*?

Visto ser natural da Guiné, não deveria ser esta a primeira palavra a aparecer?

Comment: Acho que para qualificar uma nacionalidade, eu diria: nacionalidade portuguesa-guineense ou guineense-portuguesa. Como no meu caso: nacionalidade americana-brasileira. Em todo caso, não usaria luso porque uma nacionalidade não pode ser "luso", so portuguesa.

Comment: @Lambie Sério que não se deve usar "luso" nesse caso? De acordo com o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/lusitano) "lus(itan)o" é essencialmente um sinônimo para "português" nesse sentido.

Comment: @stafusa Sim, séria. [:)]. Você diria: eu sou luso-brasileira? Eu sou anglo-americana? Nesse caso, isso se refere à cultura da pessoa, mas *não a nacionalidade em si*. [só, erro meu acima] E não preciso do dicionário para isso. Tem um pouco de confiança em mim. :)

Comment: É possível conseguir uma resposta mais fundamentada?

Comment: lusitano, segundo o Priberam, luso é ajetivo e nome. Só que fica ambíguo. Olha esse artigo: “Mais frequentemente os que obtêm ou já tinham dupla nacionalidade **portuguesa/brasileira**, mas também os que têm dupla nacionalidade **italiana/brasileira, alemã/brasileira** (casos de médicos oriundos do Rio Grande do Sul) ou francesa/brasileira”, informou a Ordem.https://www.tvpampa.com.br/numero-de-medicos-brasileiros-inscritos-em-portugal-dobra-em-5-anos/

Comment: Direito da Nacionalidade Portuguesa e Brasileira O presente estudo tem por escopo principal, desvendar alguns dos meandros, não só da nacionalidade portuguesa, mas também da brasileira.
Foi dissecada a legislação de ambos os países, sendo examinadas as diversas formas de aquisição da nacionalidade, https://www.amazon.com.br/Nacionalidade-Portuguesa-Brasileira-Meirelles-Bernardes-ebook/dp/B00NXD33HS

Comment: Prefeitura de São Paulo: nacionalidade portuguesa/brasileira http://www.birigui.sp.gov.br/birigui/controle/arquivo/lei_6.608.pdf

Comment: Já me parece suficiente para mostra que nacionalidade vai com portuguesa. https://justica.gov.pt/Registos/Nacionalidade/Nacionalidade-portuguesa

Comment: A escolha que você fez está errada. Existe uma diferença entre qualificar a nacionalidade da pessoa e a cultura dela. Acima se ve três exemplos (para a fundamentação) para as nacionalidades, Nenhuma delas usam prefixos. Prefixos denotam a cultura da pessoa e não a nacionalidade. Que pena que ninguém queira me apoiar.

Answer (score 1):

"Luso" é um prefixo, e de acordo com a nova reforma ortográfica, [deve ser escrito com hífen](https://www.portugues.com.br/amp/gramatica/hifen.html): *luso-guineense*.

Por ser um prefixo, deve vir antes, assim como em *luso-brasileiro*. Não se diz *brasileiro luso*. Se você realmente precisar, não é errado chamar alguém de "guineense e lusitano", mas sinto que você tenha preferência por expressar isso em uma só palavra (composta).

Além disso, se a pessoa é natural de Guiné e tem como segunda nacionalidade a lusitana, o correto é escrever como acima, assim como *nipo-brasileiro* e *afro-brasileiro* são essencialmente brasileiros, e que de alguma forma são considerados nipônicos ou africanos (normalmente referindo-se à origem étnica). Uma pessoa essencialmente lusitana e com origens guineenses, por exemplo, seria chamada *guiné-lusitano*. Espero que isso responda à sua segunda pergunta.

Comment: Nada disso: **lusitano-brasileiro** para a nacionalidade. **afro-brasileiro** não é uma nacionalidade, é uma cultura, e nipo-brasileiro também, uma cultura, não uma nacionalidade. Eu sou franco-brasileira, seria ter a cultura francesa e brasileira, não a nacionalidade.

Comment: @Lambie *Afro* em *afro-brasileiro*, quando se refere a uma pessoa, costuma dizer respeito à etnia.

Comment: Pois é,  franco-brasileiro, na tua maneira de ver, seria um etnia? E nipo-brasileiro, uma etnia?  Credo. Principais Características da **Cultura Afro-Brasileira** https://www.todamateria.com.br/principais-caracteristicas-da-cultura-afro-brasileira/

Comment: É só  pensar um pouco nas ocorências que saem na internet nos sites dos governos etc. para ver que luso não se diz formalmente apesar de ser um nome, para a nacionalide portuguesa.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que para qualificar uma nacionalidade, eu diria: nacionalidade portuguesa-guineense ou guineense-portuguesa.

Como no meu caso: nacionalidade americana-brasileira. E cultura anglo-brasileira. Em todo caso, não usaria *luso* porque uma nacionalidade não pode ser "luso", so portuguesa. Nesse caso o uso de *luso* se referiria à **cultura da pessoa**, mas não a nacionalidade em si.

Ela tem cultura franco-brasileira.
Ela é de nacionalidade francesa.

Comment: *Luso* pode ser nacionalidade [de acordo com o Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/lusitano/). Poderia fornecer fontes à sua afirmação?

Comment: @GuiImamura Vocé procurou **lusitana**, não luso, e alem disso a lista não fala que luso pode ser nacionalidade. O Priberam diz isso para lusitano/a: Natural, habitante ou cidadão de Portugal. = PORTUGUÊS
Ou seja lusitano, não luso. Claro, uma pessoa de nacionalidade francesa, não diz: eu tenho a nacionalidade franco. A fonte da minha afirmação é a lógica.

Comment: [Luso é sinônimo de lusitano](https://www.dicio.com.br/luso/).

Comment: Sim, eu já falei isso. Só que no Brasil, se fala nacionalidade portuguesa/brasileira ou portuguese-brasileira, e não luso por causa da ambiguidade. Em Portugal, se diz: a nacinalidade portuguesa, não luso. https://justica.gov.pt/Como-obter-nacionalidade-portuguesa/E-casado-ou-vive-em-uniao-de-facto-com-um-portugues-ha-mais-de-3-anos

Comment: Suponho que vocé é descendente de japoneses. Então, você tem cultura nipo-brasileira.